# Keep file open while writing big data?

Tags: php

We need to export data to a csv file.

The approach is:

1. `fopen` the csv file once
2. `fputcsv` after x lines dump the data to file (`x = 100, 500 or 1000`)
3. `fclose` close it after writing all data

30.000 lines take about 1 minute to parse and write to file.

Writing after 100 lines is the fastest so far.

How can I speed my export up? It is not about our data parsing algorithms, but rather file management and writing.

Here are some relevant code blocks:

```
  // -- path and file creation functions
  $strPhpTmpDir = sys_get_temp_dir();
  $strTmpDir = $strPhpTmpDir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . uniqid();
  $bOk = mkdir($strTmpDir, 0777);
  $this->m_strTmpPath = $strTmpDir;

  $strFile = 'csv-' . time() . '-' . rand() . '.csv';
  $this->m_strTmpFile = $this->m_strTmpPath . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $strFile;

  touch($this->m_strTmpFile);

  // -- open function
  if (is_file($this->m_strTmpFile) && is_writable($this->m_strTmpFile)) {
     $this->m_oFile = fopen($this->m_strTmpFile, 'w');
  }

  // -- dump function
  foreach($arData as $arLine) {
     fputcsv($this->m_oFile, $arLine, ';', '"'); 
  }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "Writing after 100 lines is the fastest so far"? Does the writing speed become higher *after* 100 lines?

Comment: it could be helpful so see your actual (relevant) code to suggest optimizations

Comment: Writing to file after having parsed 100 lines of data is faster than parsing 500 lines and then writing to file.

Comment: Added some code blocks

Comment: Do you have all the data before you start to write or are you reading in batches and write after N lines?

Comment: I have all the data before I start.

Comment: All that space makes it so hard to read.

Comment: Then, as @DaveyBoy answered, there is not much you can do. 500 lines per second is not bad for PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've tinkered with the write interval and found that 100 is the fastest, you've probably done as much as you can.

If this is in a script called from a shell rather than a webpage, there are alternatives.

- <strike>Alternative 1 - write the export script in a compiled language rather than an interpreted one. C?</strike>
- Alternative 2 - output the CSV lines to `stdout` and pipe that output into a file within the OS using redirection
- Alternative 3 - If possible, check out the caching options within your OS

Not having tried any of the above (and option 1 was struck out after seeing your code snippet), it could be that you will get a speed up as you're closer to the OS when creating the file rather than having PHP loop and perform the writing

Comment: Thanks for the alternatives, however I must stick to PHP. Additionally I will try to tweak our parsing functions.